# How to See the XML behind the Report (RDLC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have an `ASP.NET` project(VS 2015) with reports in it.

In the solution explorer the report shows a plus sign next to it, but if I click on it nothing happens.

Basically, I can only see the designer for the report. Code only breaks in XML if there is an error in run time.

If there any way to see the XML in the design time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the answer. No idea why opening this file is not as easy as other solution explorer's components.

Also, what's the point for solution explorer to show a plus sign next to rldc file.

To see the XML behind the RLDC:

1: Highlight the  rldc in solution explorer

2: Go to  View  menu bar and open the rldc using XML Editor

Answer (score 3):

Right click RDLC File in Solution Explorer and select Open with...
In Open With Window select XML Editor