# RDL files are opening up in XML format in Visual Studio 2022. I have the Microsoft RDLC Report Designer installed

Tags: xml, rdlc, rdl

Unable to view RDL reports in designer view as they are always opening in XML view. The report designer extension is installed, all updates have been installed and i have also tried re-installing Visual Studio. Any advice would be appreciated.

I have installed the RDLC Report Designer and was expecting the reports to open in this format rather than XML.

Comment: RDLC is an HTML script (not XML).  XML and HTML look very similar but are not the same.  What does first line of the file look like?

Comment: I need the reporter view in Visual Studio. The XML view i am getting begins with this. 1<XML version 1.0> and then hundreds of rows of code below it. I need it to show the report i actually built with the column headers/rows etc.. Is there a way to upload a screenshot as that would be the best way to show you what i mean.

Comment: You may be getting errors.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330554/how-to-see-the-xml-behind-the-report-rdlc